# ActionBlock Completion.Wait state seems to hang entire program

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library

The program below works as I intend, it demonstrates that two different ActionBlocks use two different threads.  However, everything I've read says that I should use the ActionBlock.Completion.Wait() in order to allow the ActionBlock to finish its work.  When I add that (currently commented out) to this program, it hangs.

Is it because I'm trying to launch ActionBlocks from the UI thread?  Should I wrap the whole mess in a BackGroundWorker?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
Protected _theConn As SqlConnection
Protected _DataList As New List(Of UISyncer)
Protected _TableList As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    _theConn = New SqlConnection("Server=USFRNDCUSHING2\MSSQSERVER2012;Database=ActionTaskTest;User Id=sa;Password=Sa1234;")
    _DataList.Add(New UISyncer("ActionTaskOne", txtParallel1))
    _DataList.Add(New UISyncer("ActionTaskTwo", txtParallel2))

    _TableList.Add("ActionTaskOne")
    _TableList.Add("ActionTaskTwo")

End Sub

Private Function ReadFromTable(ByVal tableName As String) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim adapt As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim selectString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & tableName

    adapt.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(selectString, _theConn)
    _theConn.Open()
    adapt.Fill(ds, tableName)
    _theConn.Close()

    Return ds
End Function

Private Sub readBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles readBtn.Click
    txtOut1.ResetText()

    DoTheWorkSimpler()

End Sub

Private Sub DoTheWorkSimpler()
    For Each tableName As String In _TableList
        Dim dsResult As DataSet = ReadFromTable(tableName)
        DealWithDataSet(dsResult, 1, tableName)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DealWithDataSet(ByRef dsResult1 As DataSet, ByVal maxDegreeOfParallelism As Integer, ByVal tableName As String)


    Dim workerBlock = New ActionBlock(Of DataRow)(Function(dr) DoStuff(dr), New ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism})

    For Each dr As DataRow In dsResult1.Tables(tableName).Rows
        workerBlock.Post(dr)
    Next
    workerBlock.Complete()

    'Here is my question, why does this hang my program
    'workerBlock.Completion.Wait()  'This just seems to hang the whole danged thing.

End Sub

'This might want to be shared, if it wasn't writing to the text box
Private Function DoStuff(ByRef dr As DataRow)

    Dim theString As String = dr("TaskDesc").ToString() & " on Thread: " & Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId & Environment.NewLine
    AppendTextBox(theString)

    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Sub AppendTextBox(value As String)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf AppendTextBox), New Object() {value})
        Return
    End If
    txtOut1.Text += value
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Don't use `Wait`, especially not from the UI thread. Use `await` instead.

Comment: I was able to use Await to do what I wanted.  Thank you.  So, how do I mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: You can't. And you shouldn't since I didn't really put any effort. You should add your answer explaining what was wrong and how you solved it. You can make it community wiki if you want.